# how to use (yml)string in form label rails for internationalization?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, internationalization

I want to display a **name** in 'es', 'en', 'de' and many others, hence, I have used the string `:name` and it is stored in **en.yml**, **es.yml** and others files. In order to manipulate them I have done it like this (see below):

```
<%= form.label :name %>
```

**On en.yml**

```
#contact form 
helpers:
  label:
  message:
    name: Name123
    email: Email
    subject: Subject
    body: Body
```

**This is not working. so please help.! As I am not aware of how to actually implement it.**

**Thanks**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**bugs idetified:** Indentation issues in `.yml` files.

**descriptive solutions:** use correct indentation.

**corrected source code:** see below

```
#contact form 
helpers:
  label:
    message: #name of the variable
      name: Name123
      email: Email
      subject: Subject
      body: Body
```